# Matching two or more column value and display in a single column in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have two table in SQL Server.
**tbl_Invoice** as consider bellow

PayDate ----  Amount
2017-08-23 |     2300
2017-08-23 |     2400
2017-08-23  | 2500
2017-08-24  | 5000

second Table
**tbl_Expense** as consider bellow
ExpDate ----     ExpAmount
2017-08-23  | 1700
2017-08-25  | 2800
2017-08-25  | 2900

I want to join this two table and display the sum of receipt amount and expense amount of date.
I want the output to be displayed as bellow

Date   -------      Amount ---   ExpAmount
2017-08-23 |     7200   |   1700
2017-08-24  | 5000      | 0
2017-08-25  | 0         |5700

Comment: What have you tried to do ?  Pls post your query

Comment: What should happen if _both_ tables are missing a certain date completely?

Answer (score 2):

A full outer joins between the two tables would bring you close to the output you want.  I say close because this approach still suffers from the problem of a given date not appearing in *either* table.  In such a case, this date would simply not appear in your results.  To get around this, one option would be to join to a calendar table containing all dates.  Note that I aggregate both tables by date to get the total amounts.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t1.PayDate, t2.ExpDate) AS Date,
    COALESCE(t1.Amount, 0)           AS Amount,
    COALESCE(t2.ExpAmount, 0)        AS ExpAmount
FROM
(
    SELECT PayDate, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
    FROM tbl_Invoice
    GROUP BY PayDate
) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT ExpDate, SUM(ExpAmount) AS ExpAmount
    FROM tbl_Expense
    GROUP BY ExpDate
) t2
    ON t1.PayDate = t2.ExpDate
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 1):

By simplest way try this

```
select  date , sum(Amount) as Amount ,sum(ExpAmount) as ExpAmount from 
(select PayDate as date , Amount, 0 as ExpAmount from tbl_Invoice
union 
select ExpDate as date,0 as Amount, ExpAmount from tbl_Expense ) as a 
group by date
```

**Output**

```
date                    Amount  ExpAmount
2017-08-23 00:00:00.000 7200    1700
2017-08-24 00:00:00.000 5000    0
2017-08-25 00:00:00.000 0       5700
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH suminv AS
  (SELECT paydate,sum(amount) AS amount FROM tbl_invoice group by paydate),
 sumexp as 
  (SELECT expdate,sum(expamount) AS expamount FROM tbl_expense group by expdate)
SELECT 
  coalesce(expdate,paydate) AS date,
  coalesce(amount,0),
  coalesce(expamount,0)
   FROM sumexp full outer join suminv
    on paydate=expdate
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to get all the dates you're interested and use CROSS APPLY to get the sum of values for each date:

```
SELECT 
    Dates.Date, 
    ISNULL(Invoices.Amount, 0)    AS Amount, 
    ISNULL(Expenses.ExpAmount, 0) AS ExpAmount
FROM (SELECT ExpDate As [Date] FROM tbl_Expense UNION SELECT PayDate FROM tbl_Invoice) AS Dates
CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT SUM(Amount) as Amount FROM tbl_Invoice WHERE PayDate = [Date]) AS Invoices
CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT SUM(ExAmount) as ExpAmount FROM tbl_Expense WHERE ExpDate = [Date]) AS Expenses
```